# Clicking page 2 directs me back to landing page after submit button

Tags: php, html

I have a page with a drop down list and a button. When the button is clicked I run a query and return the results from my database 10 at a time with a page for each set of 10. When I click on the page 2 button it returns to the initial state of the SearchPage.

Initial State [image: i.imgur.com/cUMb9TC.jpg]

Page Numbers [image: i.imgur.com/MBIFxAJ.jpg]

After page select [image: i.imgur.com/cUMb9TC.jpg]

My Code [image: i.imgur.com/uTX222o.png]

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
{

    $varietal=$_POST['varietal'];
    $results_per_page = 10;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM winery WHERE wine_primary = '" . $varietal . "' OR wine_secondary = '" . $varietal . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results / $results_per_page);

    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;


// Formatting and display code would be here (not shown)


// Here is the page change code
for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
{
    echo '<a href="SearchPage.php?page=' . $page .  '" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 15px; Color: white; text-align: center">' . $page . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Before posting everything as images, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @FF-, not sure if you actually looked at my post but as you can see the description and code related to the post as plain text. The images are their to supplement the provided info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on this code, the $varietal value is recieved via a POST request, but the next page link is a GET request (hyperlinks cause GET HTTP Requests by default). When the link is clicked, $_POST['varietal']  doesn't exist, because $_POST only has values on POST requests. I suggest  converting the link into a form with a submit button, and passing in the previously selected $varietal and next page number as hidden inputs.